# Finding garbage collection roots

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Is there an API to have WinDBG-SOS-like features in **.NET**?

Given an object, I would like to know how many roots are keeping it alive at runtime from C# within the same process.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible on the level of runtime. Optimized code can skip stack and go straight to CPU. So I'm wondering what output do you expect from this API?

Comment: No API. You want a memory profiler, of which there are several. Your favorite web search engine can help you out there.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov basically what you can achieve with WinDBG; find the objects in memory and their roots.

Comment: @Uno I wanted to point out the fact that imho if it was added to runtime API then it would be strange 'cause it would be an API that gives reasonable information only for debug builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ClrMD**

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime

And I wrote a small example:

https://github.com/UnoSD/ClrMdExample

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. How all those profiles would work if not? This is called Profiling API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404386(v=vs.110).aspx .

The API itself is unmanaged (COM object). But there is nothing that could stop you to use it from managed code through a RCW.

I am not sure and in doubt if you can profile a process from within itself. I think the profiler must be in another process. Though I see no issue to have process to process communication and feed the data back to the profiled process through some communication method like named pipes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at the documentation later; do you also have any link to some example?

Comment: Sorry I was probably wrong about being able to write a managed profiler :(

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736845/is-is-possible-to-use-profiling-api-right-from-c You can find interesting blog reference in that post

Comment: Digging deeper I found even more interesting things:
http://www.topholt.com/c-clr-profiler/
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/pex/wiki/Microsoft.ExtendedReflection.html

Comment: This looks like a very good starting point for your task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898078/obtaining-global-roots-from-net-programs